# GCP VM startup script cannot install brownie

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, startup, brownie

I am trying to install brownie on a GCP VM instance running ubuntu 18.04 LTS minimal.
My startup script is the following:

```
apt-get update -y && 
apt-get upgrade -y && 
apt-get install python3-pip -y && 
apt-get install nodejs npm -y &&
pip3 install cython &&
pip3 install eth-brownie;
```

When I check the startup script logs when I SSH into the VM, the logs state:

```
cat /var/log/syslog

Aug 25 10:35:16 brownie-node google_metadata_script_runner[2021]: startup-script: Collecting regex==2021.8.28 (from eth-brownie)
Aug 25 10:35:16 brownie-node google_metadata_script_runner[2021]: 2022/08/25 10:35:16 logging client: rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = transport: metadata: GCE metadata "instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Flogging.write" not defined
Aug 25 10:36:38 brownie-node google_metadata_script_runner[2021]: startup-script:   Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4f9beb9518>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/regex/
Aug 25 10:36:39 brownie-node google_metadata_script_runner[2021]: 2022/08/25 10:36:39 logging client: rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = transport: metadata: GCE metadata "instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Flogging.write" not defined
Aug 25 10:36:53 brownie-node google_metadata_script_runner[2021]: startup-script:   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement regex==2021.8.28 (from eth-brownie) (from versions: )
```

How do I properly install brownie via startup script?

Comment: Sounds like your VM doesn't have a Public IP. If you want to install stuff the VM has to be able to reach the internet, so either a Public IP or Cloud NAT

Comment: Hm that is an odd error, the VM does sit behind a Cloud NAT. What is strange to me in general is if I SSH into the VM, and just execute the last command of the startup script `pip3 install eth-brownie`, it installs with no issues.

Comment: Aha than check the scopes of the vm, it seems like the google_metadata_script_runner is not able to write logs from the errors shared above

Comment: Edit your question with details on the VM's **Access Scopes**. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes

Comment: How many (min and max) ports do you have allocated per-VM with your CloudNAT setup?  Perhaps, by the time your startup script gets to the pip3 insgtall eth-brownie there are no more ports available for CloudNAT to use.  If it takes you "a little while" to ssh into the VM and execute the command manually, some ports may have freed-up.